# How to prevent 'missing library' error linux

Tags: linux, shared, loader

I am working on a cross platform, building on PC running on ARM.
I have several targets with different sets of shared libraries. 
I am building a single executable which is linked with all the shared libraries.
I can't run it on targets that some shared libraries missing on. I get loader error.

Is there a way to 'tell' the loader to ignore the missing shared libs?
I will deal the the missing functions in run-time, I really need one executable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot tell the dynamic loader to ignore missing libraries.

What you *can* do is load the libraries dynamically using functions like `dlopen` and `dlsym`.